# How do I iterate through an array of type Timer and set each timer equal to nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, nstimer

I am trying to iterate through an array of timers to set each timer equal to nil. I am met with this error:

> Cannot assign to value: 'timer' is a 'let' constant

When I use the following code:

```
var timers = [Timer?]()

func clearTimers() {
    for timer in timers {
        timer!.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Assigning `nil` to the local `timer` variable wouldn't do what you want even if you could.  You need to remove the timer from the array.  Simply call `timers.removeAll(keepingCapacity:false)` (or `true` if you plan on adding new timers back into the array)

Comment: Iterate through the `indices` not through the timers.

Comment: Why do you want to set timers to nil? invalidating timer is enough. Also change timer!.invalidate() to timer?.invalidate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing an array of optionals doesn't make much sense, so start by simply declaring your `timers` array as:

```
var timers = [Timer]()
```

Then you can iterate through the timers to invalidate them and remove all of the references from the array to deallocate them:

```
func clearTimers() {
    for timer in timers {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    timers.removeAll(keepingCapacity:false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `for timer in timers` gives you a new reference — you are not looking at the actual Optional timer in its place in the *array*. Instead, iterate through the array itself (by way of its `indices`):

```
func clearTimers() {
    for ix in timers.indices {
        timers[ix]?.invalidate()
        timers[ix] = nil
    }
}
```